# Insert value into table if conidition is met at least one time

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have created the following `DataModel`:

[image]

Table **Customer**

```
INSERT INTO test.customer
(CustomerName, CustomerCountry, RegistrationDate)
VALUES 
("Customer A","DE","2015-05-03"),
("Customer B","US","2015-07-25"), 
("Customer C","US","2016-02-15"), 
("Customer D","DE","2017-09-21"), 
("Customer E","AU","2018-12-07");
```

Table **Orders**

```
INSERT INTO test.orders
(idCustomer, PaymentMethod, OrderDate)
VALUES 
("1","CreditCard","2015-05-04"),
("1","PayPal","2015-11-18"), 
("3","PayPal","2017-09-04"), 
("2","Invoice","2018-04-30");
```

All this works fine so far.

---

Now I want to fill the table `SpecialCustomers` with values from the table `Customer` and `Orders` based on `WHERE` conditions. Therefore, I tried the following code:

```
INSERT INTO test.specialcustomers
(idCustomer, CustomerName)
SELECT idCustomer, CustomerName
FROM test.customer
LEFT JOIN test.orders ON test.customer.idCustomer = test.orders.idCustomer
WHERE PaymentMethod ="PayPal";
```

which causes the error:

```
Error Code: 1052. Column 'idCustomer' in field list is ambiguous
```

As far as I can see the issue is that `Customer A` has both an order with `Paypal` and `CreditCard` so the `PaymentMethod` assigned to the `Customer A` is not unique.

However, my target is to insert each customer into the table `SpecialCustomers` as soon as a **condition is met at least one time**. 
Therefore, - in the case above - if at least one order is paid with `PayPal` the customer should be inserted into the table `SpeicalCustomers`.

What do I need to change in my code to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`idCustomer` column in both table, so add the table name in select query.

```
INSERT INTO test.specialcustomers
(idCustomer, CustomerName)
SELECT test.customer.idCustomer, CustomerName
FROM test.customer
LEFT JOIN test.orders ON test.customer.idCustomer = test.orders.idCustomer
WHERE PaymentMethod ="PayPal";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing aliases in the select:

```
INSERT INTO test.specialcustomers (idCustomer, CustomerName)
SELECT c.idCustomer, c.CustomerName
FROM test.customer c
LEFT JOIN test.orders o
    ON c.idCustomer = o.idCustomer
WHERE o.PaymentMethod = 'PayPal';
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify the full qualified name in your insert into columns and in your select statement if they are ambiguous. Hint: Use aliases in your from clause

Answer (score 1):

Here you just have to specify wich IdCustomer you want to insert, as you have done a `left join`, I think it's IdCustomer from table `customer` :

```
INSERT INTO test.specialcustomers
 (idCustomer, CustomerName)
SELECT c.idCustomer, c.CustomerName
FROM test.customer c
 LEFT JOIN test.orders o ON tc.idCustomer = o.idCustomer
WHERE o.PaymentMethod ="PayPal";
```